# Can we bind entire object in to back-end in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am aware about binding properties of object, i.e Height of TextBox, Width of TextBox, but is it possible to bind the entire object with ViewModel (VM) ? i.e. Binding whole TextBox to tb1(Of Type TextBox) in VM ? It may give great convenience for programmer avoiding tedious tasks of binding every properties of Object.

Comment: Why do you need entire TextBox at ViewModel? Its not MVVM-able.

Comment: @stukselbax: Why not? I can use it in VM. Actually I am cleaning one big code which one was code behind previously, so takes a lot time to bind each and every property, that's why I need.

Comment: If you want to follow MVVM pattern - follow. But if you are going to copy-paste code-behind to the VM, its better to keep it in code behind, and stop this nonsense.

Comment: *Why not? I can use it in VM*... no, you can't. View models shouldn't know anything about views. Putting UI elements into a view model breaks the 'Separation of Concerns' that it provides, rendering it all but pointless. I suggest that you read up about MVVM, because you have a very distorted view of it at present.